# ': not a valid identifier Read and Curl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

```
#!/bin/bash
# Connection to CR 
read -p "CRIP: " varCRIP
read -p "CRUSER: " varCRUSER
read -p "CRPASS: " varCRPASS
echo curl -k -X GET “http\://$varCRIP/cgi-bin/CGILink\?cmd=validate\&user=$varCRUSER\&passwd=$varCRPASS”
#curl -k -X GET “http\://$varCRIP/cgi-bin/CGILink\?cmd=validate\&user=$varCRUSER\&passwd=$varCRPASS"
```

> ```
> btude@DESKTOP-SQI0GTI:~$ ./ccr.sh
> ': not a valid identifiervarCRIP
> ': not a valid identifiervarCRUSER
> ': not a valid identifiervarCRPASS
> curl -k -X GET “http:///cgi-bin/CGILink?cmd=validate&user=&passwd=”
> ```

HELP!

I am trying to input data in a var then insert it in a curl command to run

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes `”` look weird. This could mean you have a non-breakable space in your thing because you copy/pasted from MS-Word or something.

Try this (retyped the space  manually):

```
read -p "CRIP:" varCRIP
read -p "CRUSER:" varCRUSER
read -p "CRPASS:" varCRPASS
```

Then change your quotes:

```
curl -k -X GET 'http\://$varCRIP/cgi-bin/CGILink\?cmd=validate\&user=$varCRUSER\&passwd=$varCRPASS'
```

Comment: btude@DESKTOP-SQI0GTI:~$ ./ccr.sh
    ': not a valid identifiervarCRIP
    ': not a valid identifiervarCRUSER
    ': not a valid identifiervarCRPASS
    curl -k -X GET http\://$varCRIP/cgi-bin/CGILink\?cmd=validate\&user=$varCRUSER\&passwd=$varCRPASS

Comment: Yeah I edited. Try again, might be this weird space thing.

Comment: Very strange now I just have
    read -p "CRIP:" varCRIP
    read -p "CRUSER:" varCRUSER
    read -p "CRPASS:" varCRPASS
    echo $varCRIP $varCRPASS $varCRUSER

Output is
    btude@DESKTOP-SQI0GTI:~$ ./ccr.sh
    ': not a valid identifiervarCRIP
    ': not a valid identifiervarCRUSER
    ': not a valid identifiervarCRPASS

Comment: It is the editor I was using. thank you